# IActionResult adds unnecessary parts to the json text

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to return json object from API. It theory it works but something wraps my data to unnecessary "object", including formatters, contentTypes, declaredType, statusCode:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "foo",
      "values": [
        {
          "pointName": "bar",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatters": [],
  "contentTypes": [],
  "declaredType": null,
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

When I except only

```
[
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "foo",
      "values": [
        {
          "pointName": "bar",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This problem came when I needed to return some error codes (Like forbidden or badrequest). I changed return object type from IEnumerable<ListObject> to IActionResult. My code is next:

```
public class ListObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectValue> values { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectValue
{
    public string pointName { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("getPointDataList/{deviceName}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ListObject>),StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult getPointDataList(string deviceName, [FromBody] string[] points)
{
    
    try
    {
        if (points == null || points.Length == 0)
            return BadRequest("No points defined on request");
        return getPointDataListInternal(deviceName, points);  //This function return type is IActionResult, and it returns Ok(ListObject)
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }            
}
```

Is there any easy/reasonable way to get rid of this unnesecary stuff of return object? I'm using C# in .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: StatusCode is proof that you request has been answered correctly (`return Ok()`), others I guess are parameters attached automatically by the response

Comment: "I'm trying to return json object from API" And what code are you using for this? Can you post it too, pls

Comment: @Ilkka Please accept an answer if there's one that answers your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

They are not unnecessary values, they are part of an `IActionResult`, or more specifically of an `ObjectResult` which `IActionResult` implements. So by changing the return type to `IActionResult` you also return those properties.

The StatusCode, for example, is so that it's possible to tell how the request went. Like `200 Ok`, `400 BadRequest` and so on. So when you, in your code, returns a `BadRequest("No points defined on request");` the StatusCode is 400. Any kind of http request has a status code, whether it used for webpages, API requests etc.

You can read more about the different properties of `ObjectResult` here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score -1):

Answering to my own post. Problem was not in my post. Reason to odd behavior was that I was returning Ok two times. (Ok(Ok(data)).

Removing second Ok did solve my problem.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getPointDataList/{deviceName}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ListObject>),StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult getPointDataList(string deviceName, [FromBody] string[] points)
{
    
    try
    {
        if (points == null || points.Length == 0)
            return BadRequest("No points defined on request");
        return getPointDataListInternal(deviceName, points);  //This function return type is IActionResult, and it returns Ok(ListObject)
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }            
}
protected IActionResult getPointDataListInternal(string deviceName, string[] points)
{
    return Ok(getPointDataListInternal(deviceName, points, null);  //<-Nested Ok here! Removing Ok() from here did solve the problem.
}

protected IActionResult getPointDataListInternal(string deviceName, string[] points, object xxx)
{
    //code
    return Ok(returnvalue);
}
```